# Visio - how can I generate pdf?

Tags: pdf, latex, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

How can I generate a PDF file in Visio?
I want to include this file as Figure in LaTeX, so I need  only my diagram on pdf instead of entire page with diagram on it. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean choosing `File` > `Save As` and setting the file type to PDF? Or is your question about setting a PDF figure as a full page in LaTeX?

Comment: I want to be able to generate PDF from one draving in Visio document. I want something like this: http://min.us/mcPU5vG , but not like this: http://min.us/mbjNYja

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File-> Save As -> Change File Type to PDF (the actual description in Visio 2010 is "Save As Type...").

To get the size down to what you want, assuming you are using Visio 2010 - go to the Design ribbon at the top, and change "Size" to "Fit to Drawing"

Comment: Yes, this saves the ENTIRE PAGE as pdf. I want only a drawing to be all that is on pdf.

Comment: I just re-read the question and added info about how to resize your canvas to fit your drawing.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I would vote up but I don't have 15 reputation ;P

Comment: You do have it now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Install a pdf printer like [DoPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/) and "print" to it.

Comment: Will this print selection only as an entire printing? I already have pdf printer pdfFactory Pro. I would like to pererve vector-character of drawing.